# Numbering dates from Sunday to Saturday

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, window-functions, recursive-query

Does anyone have a easy solution to make a numbering from sunday to saturday and generate the dates in PostgreSQL(version 11).I have the below solution but it is limited to only 5 weeks and i need something that is flexible.

I have dates as a column in my source table, i want those dates to be numbered from saturday to sunday like below.

**Current Query**

```
 WITH CTE AS
    (                
    SELECT  1 as rno,generate_series(  date_trunc('week', current_date)::date - 1
    ,   date_trunc('week', current_date)::date + 5
    , interval  '1 day') current_week
    )
    ,CTE_1 AS
    (
    SELECT  rno,current_week FROM CTE   
    UNION
    select 2,dt::date d from generate_series( (SELECT MIN(current_week)::DATE FROM CTE)- interval '7 days', (SELECT MIN(current_week)::DATE FROM CTE)- interval '1 days', interval '1 days') dt
    )
    ,CTE_2 AS
    (
    SELECT  rno,current_week FROM CTE_1
    UNION
    select 3,dt::date d from generate_series( (SELECT MIN(current_week)::DATE FROM CTE_1)- interval '7 days', (SELECT MIN(current_week)::DATE FROM CTE_1)- interval '1 days', interval '1 days') dt
    )
    ,CTE_3 AS
    (
    SELECT  rno,current_week FROM CTE_2
    UNION
    select 4,dt::date d from generate_series( (SELECT MIN(current_week)::DATE FROM CTE_2)- interval '7 days', (SELECT MIN(current_week)::DATE FROM CTE_2)- interval '1 days', interval '1 days') dt
    )
    ,last_5_weeks as
    (
    SELECT  rno,current_week FROM CTE_3
    UNION
    select 5,dt::date d from generate_series( (SELECT MIN(current_week)::DATE FROM CTE_3)- interval '7 days', (SELECT MIN(current_week)::DATE FROM CTE_3)- interval '1 days', interval '1 days') dt
    )
    SELECT rno,current_week::DATE as selected_date FROM last_5_weeks order by selected_date DESC
```

**Current output**

```
 rno  Date
    1   "2020-10-24"
    1   "2020-10-23"
    1   "2020-10-22"
    1   "2020-10-21"
    1   "2020-10-20"
    1   "2020-10-19"
    1   "2020-10-18"
    2   "2020-10-17"
    2   "2020-10-16"
    2   "2020-10-15"
    2   "2020-10-14"
    2   "2020-10-13"
    2   "2020-10-12"
    2   "2020-10-11"
    3   "2020-10-10"
    3   "2020-10-09"
    3   "2020-10-08"
    3   "2020-10-07"
    3   "2020-10-06"
    3   "2020-10-05"
    3   "2020-10-04"
    4   "2020-10-03"
    4   "2020-10-02"
    4   "2020-10-01"
    4   "2020-09-30"
    4   "2020-09-29"
    4   "2020-09-28"
    4   "2020-09-27"
    5   "2020-09-26"
    5   "2020-09-25"
    5   "2020-09-24"
    5   "2020-09-23"
    5   "2020-09-22"
    5   "2020-09-21"
    5   "2020-09-20"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using arithmetics?

```
select 1 + (row_number() over(order by dt desc) - 1) / 7 rn, dt::date dt
from generate_series(
    date_trunc('week', current_date)::date + 5 - interval '5 week -1 day',
    date_trunc('week', current_date)::date + 5,
    '1 day'
) s(dt)
order by dt desc
```

`generate_series()` produces all dates at once. You control the number of weeks that are generated with the value given to `week` in the literal interval. Then, in the outer query, we use `row_number()` to enumerate the week numbers.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=db3a6ed2f8e906e9f67cdfc46cb196a8)**

Answer (score 0):

One sequence for weeks and another one for days. It is flexible, 5 is a parameter. `date_trunc('week',now()+'P1W'::interval)::date-2` is this week's saturday.

```sql
select 
 w rno,
 date (date_trunc('week',now()+'P1W'::interval)::date-2 + make_interval(weeks => 1-w, days => 1-d)) "Date"
 from generate_series(1, 5, 1) w
 cross join generate_series(1, 7, 1) d;
```